# Where can I find out if I have the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, version

Where can I find out if I have the 32-bit or 64-bit version of Eclipse?

Comment: You can just look at the task manager.  If there is a *32 next to the process its a 32-bit process.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to

> Help -> About Eclipse -> Installation Details

Click on `'Configuration'` tab:

Scroll down and look for  `osgi.arch` in in textbox, '`x86`' indicates 32 bit and '`x86_64`' indicates 64 bit eclipse.